# How do curly braces and scope wоrk in C?

Tags: c, scope, curly-braces

I'm currently trying to learn some C in my spare time. I have some experience in Java, and I'm therefore used to limit scoping of i.e. variables with curly braces. But I'm a bit confused, as it seems like Brian W. Kernighan/Dennis M. Ritchie's book "The C Programming Language" doesn't use a lot of curly braces, where I would assume it's normal to use them (from a Java perspective). E.g. 1.6 in the book where the code is:

```
while((c = getchar())) != EOF)
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        ++ndigit[c-'0'];
    else if() /*and so forth...*/
        ++nwhite;
    else
        ++nother;
```

From a Java perspective I'm used to that only the first statement would be run then, because of the lack of curly braces, but the indentation suggests that everything will run (if, else if and else).

So what I'm asking is: What would run here, and why would it run? Are if, else if and else all in the scope of the while loop? Are there any conventions to refer to, that I can read to try to understand it better? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a rule of thumb you can say, that if you have a statment like `if`/`while` the immediate following line can be seen as the statement's body, in this case you have a nested construction

Comment: Using braces here is optional in Java as in C: an "if" statement [may have an "else" clause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9), which has an attached statement, which could be another "if", so a full cascade of "if ... else if ... else if ... else" is the while loop's single body statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `while`, `if`, `else if`, and `else` are followed by a single statement.  This statement can be an actual line of C, or a block statement (surrounded by braces).  The `if`, `else if`, and `else` are considered as one block.

So using braces, this would be the equivalent:

```
while((c = getchar())) != EOF) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        ++ndigit[c-'0'];
    }
    else if() {  /*and so forth...*/
        ++nwhite;
    }
    else {
        ++nother;
    }
}
```

Comment: And, actually, that is the same in Java. Even if it is error prone, and hence I tend not to use it.

Comment: Ok, thanks alot for answer! But I don't really understand why everything in that while-loop with curly braces are equivalent with the one without the curly braces. As far as I can tell, it's more than one statement in the while loop. I.e.    
    if(something)
        ++something;
        ++somethingElse;
is not allowed, but

    while(1 == 1)
        if(something) {
            ++something;
            ++somethingElse;
        }
is allowed? If this is correct, that must mean it's different rules for if and while concerning curly braces?

Comment: Actually, the `if statement` itself (including an optional else clause with its statement) is one statement.

Comment: As described in my answer, curly braces group several statements together to act like one statement.

Comment: The `if`, `else if`, and `else` statements together are considered as one big block.  You can go deeper, so the nested `if`, `else if`, `else` statements are also considered as one big block

Answer (score 2):

In C, as in Java, an `ìf` and a `while` has one statement as its body, and `if` can have an optional `else` clause with one statement as its body. And in most places where you can have one statement, you can have a statement block, which is a list of statements surrounded by curly braces. This is not different in C than in Java.

In order to avoid ambiguity, if there are two ifs and one else, the else is defined to refer to the last one.
I. e.

```
if(a) x if(b) y else z
```

is defined to mean

```
if(a) x { if(b) y else z }
```

and not

```
if(a) x { if(b) y } else z
```

Here, x, y, and z are statements - which can be statement blocks as well.

However, having said all this, it is error prone to leave off the braces, and hence many coding guidelines suggest to always use the curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

If an if statement does not contain a curly brace, you can inline up to one semi colon after, and it will automatically assume the curly braces as such:

```
while((c = getchar())) != EOF){
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        ++ndigit[c-'0'];
    }
    else if() /*and so forth...*/
    {
        ++nwhite;
    }
    else
    {
        ++nother; 
    }
 }
```

So this is valid:

```
 while(true) i++;
```

And this should not be valid:

```
 while(true) i++; break; printf("hello");

 if(true) printf("Hello"); break;
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `you can inline up to one semi colon after` what about `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) ...` more then one **semi colon**. The term you are looking for is *statement*

Comment: @amit Well, statement. Also, no "semi-colons are assumed". Nothing is "assumed" at all, let alone syntactical elements or tokens.

Comment: Wanted to help you with your indentation and you refused my edit... Oh well, stay in your unreadable code world then...

Comment: didn't mean to, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You may just treat `if/else if/else` instructions as one block - they can't  really be divided, `else` cannot exist on it's own.

On the side note, it's sometimes confusing when you have a situation like

```
if(something)
   if (somethingOther)
     ....
else
   .....
```

If your code is long enough, you might get confused where to attach this `else`, so it's good to always use braces. As stated in comment, `else` always attaches to the "nearest" `if`.

Comment: Your example should not be confusing - the else always corresponds to the innermost if.

Comment: I meant that in large code blocks, with not-that-perfect formatting, one might get lost, not that it's syntactically ambiguous. Fixed in answer.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I still don't agree entirely - if the indentation is correct, then one should write that else one level deeper. Whatever...