# What is the use extra curly brackets in the code? What does it do?

Tags: c

This is a C program in which the code from "int k" and "for" loop are enclosed in the curly brackets. What is the purpose of those curly brackets?

```
   int main(){
       int k;
       {
           int k;
           for (k=0;k<10;k++);
       }
   }
```

Comment: There is no error. You shadow `k` in two separate scopes. Not wise, but not an error. Further, with any kind of optimization enabled, your code is likely eliminated. You may find [How does curly braces and scope work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082135/how-does-curly-braces-and-scope-work-in-c) useful.

Comment: You don't get errors because it's (almost) a valid and legal C program. The only thing is that you should really have `int main(void)`.

Comment: It doesn't return an error because there is none. What do you mean by "there are unwanted braces"?

Comment: Also header files are not mandatory to be included if you are not using any of its definitions in the program.

Comment: Why you declare k twice different scope? instead of initialise  ?

Comment: @AjayPandya It was a coding question given to me in a hiring challenge to solve

Comment: @ShwetaSharma you can simply declare int k=your value {for condition statement}

Comment: @ShwetaSharma I would stop immediately conversations with the company that gave you this as a coding challenge.  I've seen teams staffed with people who could (and would) answer this question.  It isn't pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no "unwanted braces" in this code.  There is an anonymous block, which is not an error.  In fact, it is allowed by the spec.

Your variable `k` is defined in the main scope, but then shadowed in the anonymous block.

```
int main() {
  int k = 0;
    {
    int k = 1;
    // do more stuff with k
    }
  // k is still 0 here.
}
```

When I was programming C, something like 1000 years ago, I would have had stern words for a dev on my team who tried using this trick.